# Get MAX,MIN,SUM,AVERAGE and create report from a single table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, linq

I am storing a flat file data from a text file with an Interval (let say hourly)
Data I am getting as below

Date (Datetime),
TotalTime(varchar(20)),
TotalCount(BigInt),
Minimum Time (varchar(20)),
Maximum Time (varchar(20)).

[image: Input Data]

I am looking for a report such like

[image: Output and Internal Calculation]

My SQL so far

```
select 
  sum(
    (CASE WHEN (isnumeric(TotalTime) = 1) 
     THEN CAST(TotalTime AS bigint)
     ELSE 0
     END)
  ) as 'TotalTime',
  sum(TotalCount) as 'TotalCount',
  AVG(
    (CASE WHEN (isnumeric(MinTime) = 1) 
    THEN CAST(MinTime AS bigint)
    ELSE 0
    END)
  ) as 'MinAvgTime',
  AVG(
    (CASE WHEN (isnumeric(MaxTime) = 1) 
    THEN CAST(MaxTime AS bigint)
    ELSE 0
    END)
  ) as 'MaxAvgTime',
  dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, InputDate)) as created
from MYTABLE
group by dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, InputDate))
```

Trying to figure out is there any way I can get that output without using LINQ..Is there any way to get it directly from a SQL query

Answer (score 0):

What result do you get from following SQL:

```
SELECT
  date(`day`) AS created,
  sum(TotalTime) AS TotalTime,
  sum(TotalCount) AS TotalCount,
  avg(MinTime) AS MinAvgTime,
  avg(MaxTime) AS MaxAvgTime
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: thank you . I am getting 5 columns where I am looking to get 10 columns from sql query . Is there any way to get it directly from a SQL query

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work for you:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(DATE, InputDate, 103) as InputDate,
    SUM(cast(TotalTime as int)) as TotalTime,
    SUM(TotalCount) as TotalCount,
    AVG(cast(MinTime as float)) as MinAvgTime,
    AVG(cast(MaxTime as float)) as MaxAvgTime 
FROM
    MYTABLE
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(DATE, InputDate, 103)
```

Comment: ..thank you ..if you see the output image there I am trying to select 10 columns . I am using the same query you provided me and thinking to use LINQ on result set . Is there any way to get it directly from a SQL query

Answer (score 0):

Use a view or CTE function and can be query from SQL directly